# Existence of a measurable set in [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to show if there is a measurable set $E$ inside $[0,1]$ such that $m\left([0,x]\cap E\right)=x/3$ for almost every $x\in [0,1]$. Here $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.
I guess such $E$ does not exist. My thought is that we can construct an absolutely continuous function $[0,1]$ and then use the fundamental theorem of Calculus.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is such an $E.$ Since $x\to m([0,x]\cap E)$ is continuous, we actually have $m([0,x]\cap E)=x/3$ for all $x\in [0,1].$ Verify that this implies $m([x,y]\cap E)= (y-x)/3$ for all $[x,y]\subset [0,1].$

Now $m(E)=m(E\cap [0,1]) = 1/3.$ So there are closed intervals $I_1,I_2,\dots $ such that $E \subset \cup I_n$ and $\sum m(I_n) < 1/2.$ Thus

$$\frac{1}{3} = m(E) \le \sum m(E\cap I_n) = \sum\frac{m(I_n)}{3} = \frac{1}{3}\sum m(I_n) < \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}.$$

That's a contradiction, proving that such an $E$ does not exist.

Comment: On what do you base "So there are closed intervals /.../"? I don't distrust the correctness of this; I just don't understand that part.

Comment: We could also say that if we define $m_E(X) := m(E \cap X)$, then we have $m_E = m/3$ because the $\pi$-system of the segments of the form $[0,x]$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$. Then we have $m(E) = m(E \cap E) = m_E(E) = m(E)/3$ and so $m(E) = 0$, contradicting the $m(E) = 1/3$.

Comment: @Idéophage I was trying to keep the answer at an elementary level.

Comment: @md2perpe $m(E) = \inf \{\sum_n m(I_n): E\subset \cup I_n\}.$

Comment: @zhw. Ok, actually the two are the same thing, I did not look well enough. But now the two versions are given.